# PHP: array_map on object?

Tags: php, oop

I'm trying to write a function that formats every (string) member/variable in an object, for example with a callback function. The variable names are unknown to me, so it must work with objects of all classes.

How can I achieve something similar to `array_map` or `array_walk` with objects?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

use [get_object_vars()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php) to get an associative array of the members, and use the functions you mentioned.

btw, you can also do a foreach on an object like you would on an array, which is sometimes useful as well.

Comment: Note that in the rare case when you're using an `ArrayObject`, you can do something like `$obj->exchangeArray(array_map('func', $obj->getArrayCopy()));`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `get_object_vars()`, but if you need more control, try using [reflection](http://web.archive.org/web/20090228224836/http://www.php.net:80/manual/en/language.oop5.reflection.php). It's slower than `get_object_vars()` (or `get_class_methods()` for that matter), but it's much more powerful.

Comment: that's a really cool functionality of php i didn't know about! I'm not exactly sure how I'd actually _use_ it, but that's still cool!

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [get_object_vars](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php) / [get_class_methods](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-class-methods.php) (the first gets the variables, the second the method names).