# PHP: how can I display the properties of my object?

Tags: php

I have an object $rows

If I use echo $rows the content is displayed in my html page, however I would like to select only some parts of the content but I cannot see inside the variable how it is structured... 
thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you looked at [var_dump](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) and friends? var_dump() works purely through side effects, so it's great as a debug aid but useless if you want to do something else with the info it spits out. That's when you reach for [var_export()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) and maybe [print_r()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php).

A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114229/php-array-map-on-object) here on SO shows additional ways to inspect your object - [get_object_vars()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php) for the object's state, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
print_r($rows);
```

to see the structure, then use

```
$rows['property_name'];
```

to access single properties

Answer (score 0):

Use var_dump/print_r or the XDebug extension to inspect your vars/objects.